# Twilio API Next Caller Plugin returns: Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, twilio, twilio-api

We are trying to use Twilio API next caller plugin "nextcaller_advanced_caller_id" & getting "Internal server error" (code: 61000). Code example:

```
    static string accountSid = "<MY_SID>";
    static string authToken = "<MY_AUTH_TOKEN>";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
        Console.WriteLine("twilio initialized");

        var addOns = new List<string> { "nextcaller_advanced_caller_id" };
        var addOnsData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "AvailableAddOnSid", "<ADON_SID>" },
            { "AcceptTermsOfService", "true" }
        };

        var fetchOptions = new FetchPhoneNumberOptions(new PhoneNumber("+16466xxxxxx<REAL_PHONE_NUMBER>"));
        fetchOptions.AddOns = addOns;
        fetchOptions.AddOnsData = addOnsData;
        var phoneNumberInfo = PhoneNumberResource.Fetch(fetchOptions);

        Console.WriteLine(phoneNumberInfo.AddOns);
    }
```

Could you please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Error 61000](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/61000) is a catch all server error for the Add-on itself. This isn't to do with your code in this case, so I recommend you [raise a ticket with Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact). They will be able to investigate what is going wrong here.